# Can I resolve a DFS path with DirectoryInfo?

Tags: .net-3.5, microsoft-distributed-file-system, directoryinfo

Is there a way to resolve a DFS path directly with `DirectoryInfo`?

I found this answer: [How can I get an active UNC Path in DFS programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938669/how-can-i-get-an-active-unc-path-in-dfs-programatically/3939235#3939235)  ... is this really my only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) provides no ability to "resolve" the active path of a DFS share. This is likely because `DirectoryInfo` is on a much higher level.

> Exposes instance methods for creating, moving, and enumerating through directories and subdirectories.

The active path on a DFS share should be considered an "implementation detail" by your application.

Comment: ... *an "implementation detail" by your application* ... that's about what I figured.